# XPath - is it possible to query the node content?

Tags: xml, dom, xpath

I've this xml

```
<root>
    <node1>
        <node2>xxx</node2>
    </node1>
    ...
    <node1>
        <node2>yyy ABC yyy</node2>
    </node1>
    ...
    <node1>
        <node2>zzz</node2>
    </node1>
</root>
```

I want to get node1 that has a node2 containing the text **ABC**.
Is it possible to achieve this using XPath?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this will do the trick:

```
node1[node2[contains(text(),"ABC")]]
```

**EDIT**: Tested, seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

`//node1[node2[contains(text(),"ABC")]]`

Comment: This only works when the text is exactly "ABC".  Jweede's answer will find any nodes which contain "ABC" in its text.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using this XPath Tester here: http://www.yetanotherchris.me/home/2010/6/7/online-xpath-tester.html.  Does this work for you?

```
//node1/node2[contains(.,"ABC")]
```

Comment: this will select node2 instead of node1.